# Nagios logging of new client

Tags: linux, logging, nagios

I have a Nagios running on Linux machine and its monitoring more than 50 Linux clients using NRPE plugin. But now I am facing some issue with the logging.

For example, If I add a new client to nagios , no information available on the main nagios log file about the new client. It is available in the log file only  after one day.

is there anything to configure on nagios to log everything in log file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [automatically add clients to nagios server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708916/automatically-add-clients-to-nagios-server)

Comment: Did you bounce the Nagios process after adding the new machine?  Were there any errors/warnings when the new Nagios process was started?